# LIKE %...% Meta Query

Tags: meta-query

I have a serialized array as a meta value and I'm trying to run WP Query where it finds a specific value in the serialized array.

Here's an example of the serialized array field:

```
a:6:{i:0;s:3:"173";i:1;s:3:"172";i:2;s:3:"171";i:3...
```

Here's my query, but it doesn't work:
The ID's are numberic I'm doing a search for as well.

```
$practiceArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'attorney',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                              'key' => 'practice_area',
                              'value' => $post->ID,
                              'compare' => 'LIKE',
                              'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                              )
                        )
);
```

I've tried using `'value' => '%'.$post-ID.'%'` in my queries, but it doesn't seem to work as well.

Anyone ever had any experience working on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I came across this same issue today. In both our situations, there is in fact a nice solution. Because the serialized data we are searching for, are simply IDs, and they are always wrapped in quotations, we just need to include the quotations as part of the query. This eliminates the problem of encountering false positives in the search results.

You just need to modify the meta query to as follows:

```
array(
    'key' => 'practice_area',
    'value' => '"'.$post->ID.'"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
)
```

This way, it searches for the whole ID, including the double quotes before and after it within the serialized array. No false positives will be included.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue once, but it's definitely not a nice place to be. The way you're approaching this you'll **never** have a consistent result -- your search will turn a lot of false positives (i.e. searching for post ID 43 will return 143, 243, 1431, 1432, etc.

The way I see it, you have two options:

- Rethink the way you're saving your meta data; use arrays for data
  that's only needed when rendering the post, but not for data that you
  need to query to filter posts. For the latter, use individual meta
  keys in your db -- it's much faster, the queries are easier to code,
  and you can rest assured that you'll have full control over what the
  queries return. Don't be concerned with using too many rows in the
  postmeta table: that's why they're there for.
- If for some reason you must have multiple fields packed in one db
  row, don't rely on default serialization: go for CSV, preferably with
  some sort of prefix, something that won't return false positives.
  Something like `"id:43,id:54,foo:bar,id:57,"`, then search for
  '`id:{post_ID},`' (note that all values should end with commas in
  order to safely use double wildcards on a LIKE search. It's sort of a hack, but it's more reliable than what you're going for right now.

For what it's worth, regarding the original question, WP already adds both wildcards when doing LIKE comparisons using `query_posts`, so you don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress LIKE is not like Mysql Like, so 'value' => '%'.$post-ID.'%' doesn't work.

You could try the REGEXP version. For example:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'attorney',
        'value'     => '^'.$post-ID,
        'compare'   => 'REGEXP',
    )
)
```

Should search for all elements where attorney begins with $post-ID value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `LIKE` with `numeric` (at least I am pretty sure you can't). `numeric` will try to convert the whole `value` to a number. That will fail, as it isn't a number.  That is the first mistake.

Secondly, to get a literal `%`, you need to double it to `%%`. Note: I can't remember about `meta_query` strictly speaking.  I am extrapolating from what it takes to get a `%` to pass through `$wpdb->prepare` I think it is the same though. **Edit:** This appears to only be true with `$wpdb->prepare`. The code has been edited.

I have not tested this, as I'd need to setup some things in my database and don't have time right now, but I think it will work.

```
$practiceArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'attorney',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'practice_area',
        'value' => $post->ID,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )
);
```

I hope that is the push you need. If it doesn't work I will revisit.

**Edit:** I inserted your (broken) serialized array into my database and ran the code above. If I get everything set up correctly-- the meta_fields, the post types, etc.-- the code above works. If it isn't working for you you've got something else going on-- maybe you think there should be a match where there isn't.

I am assuming that you are going to have an array like that for every one of your 'attorney' posts. If you do, that should work. I might lean toward multiple `practice_area` rows though, instead of using a serialized array. `=` is a more efficient query than `LIKE`, especially when you have wildcards, and your results should be more accurate. Indexing (MySQL database) should work better as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returns NIL.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Your comment regarding '%' is only true when using $wpdb->prepare. When using query_posts, using '%' is unnecessary: WP puts them in for you, whether you want them or not.

Comment: @tbuteler WP will also automatically escape % to %% in that case.