# Meta query with JSON value

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Im using post meta to store some value.
Im having the following in wp_postmeta table:

meta_key

```
mykey
```

meta_value

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

I need to return posts which have meta_value of 2.

My query:

```
$args = array(
               'post_type' => 'post',
               'meta_key' => 'mykey',
               'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
               'order' => 'ASC',
               'meta_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'key' => 'mykey',
                       'value' => '2',
                       'compare' => 'IN',
                   )
               )
             );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But no posts returned... Where i made mistake?

Comment: You cannot do such meta_query on serialized array.
Here's similar question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays

Comment: you could try `'compare' => 'LIKE', 'value' => 's:1:"2"'`, but i don't think it will work..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LIKE %...% Meta Query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85092/like-meta-query)

Answer (score 4):

That's not `json`. A semi-colon won't work inside a javaScript Object like that.

That's serialized-data. If you return that string & then call [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on it & then `var_dump` you can see what's inside.

Also, see [fuxia♦'s Answer Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95415/123674) for more info.

& to [Maikal's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/38034/maikal) credit, you can use a meta_query in this situation, but you have to use the correct syntax...

I believe, it's:

```
'compare' => 'LIKE', 
'value' => '"2"'
```

& [Darren Felton's Answer Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144290/123674) seems to verify that