# meta_query: check if number exists

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, meta-query

I'm using the following query to check if user id exists in a custom meta field:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'participantes',
        'value'   => $user_id,
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
)
```

The field `participantes` stores user ids separated by comma, like `345,1,34`.

This only works when the current user id is the first number in the list.

Comment: Please share the value of "participantes", it will help understand it. p.s. participantes is misspelled.

Comment: @M-R I edit the question

Comment: 'IN' require custom field to contain array not a string.

Comment: @PieterGoosen There is a problem using LIKE: if user id is 2 and participantes store 425, the post is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, more robust solution would be to allow multiple values of custom field 'participants'. You can store like following

```
add_post_meta($post_id,'participants','value1');
add_post_meta($post_id,'participants','value2');
add_post_meta($post_id,'participants','value3');
add_post_meta($post_id,'participants','value4');
```

Deletion would be like

```
delete_post_meta($post_id,'participants','value1');
```

Query will then change to a simpler one.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'participants',
        'value'   => $user_id,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
)
```

In case you would like to go for an array implementation, you can store values as following

```
$array = array('value1','value2','value3');
update_post_meta($post_id,'participants',$array);
```

And search can be done like

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'participants',
        'value'   => '"'.$userid.'"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
)
```

[Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85092/like-meta-query) for searching in serialized array

> This way, it searches for the whole ID, including the double quotes
>   before and after it within the serialized array. No false positives
>   will be included.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I have written a couple of answers arguing that if you need to search the data store granular data in the database, [most about using `serialize()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115837/21376) but the idea is the same. Shoving a bunch of information into a single key does you no favors.

Comment: @M-R I'm following the array path. The generated array is something like this a:1:{i:0;i:1;}, where 1 is user id. But nothing returns in query.

Comment: @M-R Found a solution: `'value' => serialize($user_id),`

Answer (score 0):

Just because the value is a series of IDs separated by commas does not mean it will be recognised as an array. Try the following.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'participantes',
        'value'   => explode( ",", $user_id),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ),
)
```